# How to make an array reject a duplicate as the user inputs them

Tags: c++

I have to ask the user to put in an array size and then  to ask the user to fill it out. When the user puts in a duplicate, the program should say "invalid" and the user is asked to replace the number. I am supposed to use traversing array search.

Like this example here:

```
Enter list size: 4
Enter value for index 0: 1
Enter value for index 1: 1
Invalid. Enter a new number: 2
Enter value for index 2: 5
Enter value for index 3: 6
```

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int size;
  cout << "Enter list size: ";
  cin >> size;
  int array1[size];

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << "Enter value for index " << i << ": ";
    cin >> array1[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
      if (array1[i] == array1[j]) {
        cout << "Invalid! Enter a new value for index " << i << ": ";
        cin >> array1[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you can't use a `std::set<int>`

Comment: `for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){` your  loop is looking for the duplicates in the elements that are not currently added yet, instead of looking only in the elements that are in the array. Think about where you should look for duplicates.

Comment: As C++ [doesn't have variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) your code is invalid from the start. Please learn how to use `std::vector`.

Comment: `int array1[size];` -- That should be `std::vector<int> array1(size);`.  If you say "I can't use std::vector`, well, your code that you were using before, as pointed out, was invalid to begin with.

Comment: @fabian Evil. :) You named your vector array but then used vector later.

Comment: `size_t size; std::cin >> size; std::vector<int> array(size); for  (auto insertPos = array.begin(); insertPos != array.end(); ++insertPos) { int input; std::cin >> input; while(std::find(array.begin(), insertPos, input) != insertPos) { std::cerr << "Duplicate value; enter another one\n"; std::cin >> input; } *insertPos = input; }`

Answer (score 1):

It does what was specified but the exercise probably was to write `std::ranges::find`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    size_t size;
    std::cout << "Enter list size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector<int> arr;
    arr.reserve(size);

    while(arr.size() < size) {
        int t;
        std::cout << "Enter value for index " << arr.size() + 1 << ": ";
        std::cin >> t;
        if (std::ranges::find(arr, t) == arr.end()) {
            arr.push_back(t);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Invalid! ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, Every time user enter value helper function will check duplicate from already filled array

```
#include<iostream>

// Helper Function that will check duplicate from array
bool IsDuplicate (int arr[] ,const int idxSoFar, int element){
    for(int i =0 ; i < idxSoFar ; i += 1 )
        if( arr[i] == element){
          std::cout << "Invalid! Enter a new value for index "<< idxSoFar + 1 << " : ";     
          return  arr[i] == element;
        }
   return false;       
}

int main () {
   int size;
   std::cout << "Enter list size: ";
   std::cin >> size;
   int array1[size];

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     std::cout << "Enter value for index " << i << ": ";
     do
       std::cin >> array1[i];
     while(IsDuplicate(array1 , i , array1[i]));
   }
   return 0;
}
```